VLC Setting Custom Options
So I am using VLC and I want to add custom options to play a stream,
I know you can set a header with the command --http-user-agent 'FooBar/1.2.3' 'http://wiki.videolan.org/'
However the stream I want to play also checks for a referrer and also the Origin, So Anyway we can set them as well in the extra options section?
